# Tap Payment Gateway in React Native and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I am developing and integrating the Tap Payment gateway in React-native (Expo) and Nodejs , anyone can help me that how to Integrate Tap payment in React-native and Nodejs

Answer (score 2):

You can hit their APIs which are also available for the Nodejs as well for creating the token and then making the payment request easily, you may use got npm for making the API request from Nodejs.

Check this link TAP API DOC - https://www.tap.company/kw/en/developers

Comment: Exactly I am not getting what to do in react-native and nodejs, can you briefly explain how to do in React-Native and Nodejs

Comment: See Work with the TAP APIs in backend and apply operations at backend side, and from react-native just call your Backend API, like your API is /payment , so in this, you will call the TAP apis and apply an operation over it,